# XmlDocument how to insert new record into an existing XML File

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

i have followed few example online with no luck , not sure what's wrong with my code.

I already have xml File and i load it into my program and has some record as

```
<RETS>
  <Servers>
    <serverInfo type="Type1" LoginString="http://rets.Login" LoginUserName="Ret124" LoginPassword="Mypassword" RetsVersion="RETS/1.5"/>
    </Servers>
  <SearchStrings>
    <search type="Type1"><![CDATA[http://rets2_3/GetMetadata]]></search>
  </SearchStrings>  
</RETS>
```

Then I let the user add new Record and it should look like this =
serverInfo type="Type2" LoginString="http:www.xml.com" LoginUserName="Re34555" etc

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("RETSDictionary.xml");
            XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("RETS/Servers/serverInfo");
            node.Attributes["type"].Value = m_type; // these values coming for text field 
            node.Attributes["LoginString"].Value = m_loginString;
            node.Attributes["LoginPassword"].Value = m_loginPassword;
            node.Attributes["LoginUserName"].Value = m_loginUserName;
            node.Attributes["RetsVersion"].Value = m_retsVersion;


            try {
                xmlDoc.Save("RETSDictionary.xml");
                m_isSuccessful = true;
                m_message = "New RETS Server saved.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                m_isSuccessful = false;
                m_message = ex.Message;
            }
```

so when it hits save nothing happens !

Comment: Are you sure that you get data fromthe document ? Have you tried displaying the data?

Comment: Please share your desired output AFTER adding a new XML fragment.

Comment: <Servers>
    <serverInfo type="Type1" LoginString="http://rets.Login" LoginUserName="Ret124" LoginPassword="Mypassword" RetsVersion="RETS/1.5"/>
    <serverInfo type="Type2" LoginString="http://2222.Login" LoginUserName="tyy" LoginPassword="Mypassword2" RetsVersion="RETS/1.5"/>
    <serverInfo type="Type3" LoginString="http://55555.Login" LoginUserName="454" LoginPassword="Mypassword3" RetsVersion="RETS/1.5"/>
    </Servers>
  <SearchStrings>
    <search type="Type1"><![CDATA[http://rets2_3/GetMetadata]]></search>
  </SearchStrings>  
</RETS>

Comment: yes i can display the  date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new element, and then appending it to the Servers node.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("RETSDictionary.xml");
XmlNode serversNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("RETS/Servers");
XmlElement node = xmlDoc.CreateElement("serverInfo");
node.SetAttribute("type", m_type); // these values coming for text field 
node.SetAttribute("LoginString", m_loginString);
node.SetAttribute("LoginPassword", m_loginPassword);
node.SetAttribute("LoginUserName", m_loginUserName);
node.SetAttribute("RetsVersion", m_retsVersion);
serversNode.AppendChild(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use LINQ to XML. This API exists already for more than ten years. And it superseded previous .Net Framework XML APIs.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\temp\RETSDictionary.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

    // compose new fragment
    XElement fragment = new XElement("serverInfo",
            new XAttribute("type", "Type2"),
            new XAttribute("LoginString", "2222.Login"),
            new XAttribute("LoginUserName", "tyy"),
            new XAttribute("LoginPassword", "Mypassword2"),
            new XAttribute("RetsVersion", "RETS/1.5")
        );

    // add new fragment to a proper location
    xdoc.Descendants("Servers").LastOrDefault().Add(fragment);

    // save back to XML file
    xdoc.Save(fileName);
}
```

> Output

```
<RETS>
  <Servers>
    <serverInfo type="Type1" LoginString="http://rets.Login" LoginUserName="Ret124" LoginPassword="Mypassword" RetsVersion="RETS/1.5" />
    <serverInfo type="Type2" LoginString="2222.Login" LoginUserName="tyy" LoginPassword="Mypassword2" RetsVersion="RETS/1.5" />
  </Servers>
  <SearchStrings>
    <search type="Type1"><![CDATA[http://rets2_3/GetMetadata]]></search>
  </SearchStrings>
</RETS>
```